# Problems with reading Data from a Usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have the following Problem, i created a C# User Control with a couple of Input fields.

I implemented 2 Main functions ( Set_Data and Read_Data). 
Set Data Reads some Data from a Class and Displays it at the User_Control.

Read_Data: Reads the Input value and stores it inside the same Class.

These functions are tested and work properly.

But if i try to use the same User Control to store the Data into another Instance of the same class the Information in the first Class stores the values of the second one too.
Maybe im just doing something wrong.

```
private Data_Class DataClass1 = new Data_Class();
private Data_Class DataClass2 = new Data_Class();

private void btn_page1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    page = "page1";
    UserControl1.set_Data(DataClass1);
    UserControl1.BringToFront();
}    

private void btn_page2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    page = "page2";
    UserControl1.set_Data(DataClass2);
    UserControl1.BringToFront();
}

private void check_pagechange_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (page != last_page)
    {
        if (last_page == "page1")
        {
            DataClass1 = UserControl1.read_Data();
        }
        if (last_page == "page2")
        {
            DataClass2 = UserControl1.read_Data();
        }
        last_page = page;
    }
}
```

As it can be seen i use a Backgroundworker which reads the Data from the Usercontrol when there is a Pagechange.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if (page == "page1")` and `if (page == "page2")` instead of `last_page` ?

Comment: I want to read the data whe i leave this page. Therefore whenever a pagechange occurs it should execute the Read_data function and store it into the respective class.

Comment: When exactly is "check_pagechange_RunWorkerCompleted" executed? The name of the method makes me assume it is executed some while after "btn_pageX_Click()"? Maybe the issue is there a race condition? From your code I cannot see anything wrong.

Comment: I just tried it without using the Background worker.
I Hardcoded the pagechange for a Quick try and the same Problem appears again.

Comment: bool variable=false;


  if (page != last_page)

        {

            if (last_page == "page1"&& variable==false)

            {
                DataClass1 = UserControl1.read_Data();
                variable=true;
           }

Even after this change it still has this behaviour.

Comment: Since you're continually reassigning your dataclass objects to your properties, if you mess up the order of operations _once_ (putting the #1 `read_Data()` object in #2 `DataClass2` or vice versa), you're going to end up with two references to the same object. The other object will be discarded and you cannot recover from this until you drop and recreate everything. I strongly suggest taking a less haphazard approach to handling these two objects as your current approach is very prone to errors like this.

Comment: May i ask you how i should do this better?